# ExchangeService email replying to another account of Microsoft Exchange

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I can reply emails in an account of microsoft exchange using any font that i want in the body of the message to gmail,hotmail and others, but when i reply to another microsoft exchange account the font of the body message looks very huge.
Anyone knows why ?

My method is this

```
[WebMethod]
        public virtual XmlDocument ResponderEmail(int contato, int seq, int empresa, string mensagem, int usuario, string emailID)
        {
            try
            {

                ExchangeService wsExchange = connectEWS();

                EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(wsExchange, emailID);

                string myReply = mensagem;
                bool replyToAll = true;

                email.Body.BodyType = BodyType.HTML;

                email.Reply(myReply, replyToAll);

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(@"<RETORNO><MOVER SUCESSO=""TRUE""/></RETORNO>");

                return xmlDoc;

            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(@"<RETORNO><RESPONDER SUCESSO=""FALSE""/></RETORNO>");
                CVMGERR01.TrataErro(erro);
                return xmlDoc;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is going to render the message based on what is in the body of the Message what maybe happening is your replying to RTF message and your having a specific conversion error. I would suggest you look at the body of the Message using a Mapi editor like MfcMapi or Outlookspy and examine the HTML. In the Managed API you can also use the CreateReply method instead which give you more control over the formatting of the response https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633704%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

cheers
Glen